# Laravel subfolder - axios post not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm trying to built SPA with Laravel and Vue using jwt in subfolder but for some reason i get 405 Method Not Allowed when load the page. Here is code:

**Method in helper.js**

```
export default {
    check() {
        return axios.post('api/auth/check').then(response =>  {
            return !!response.data.authenticated;
        }).catch(error => {
            return response.data.authenticated;
        });
    }
}
```

**Vue Routes**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(r => r.meta.requiresAuth)){
        return helper.check().then(response => {
            if (!response){
                return next({ path : '/unikit/login'});
            }

            return next();
        });
    }

    if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.requiresGuest)) {
        return helper.check().then(response => {
            if (response) {
                return next({ path : '/unikit'});
            }

            return next();
        });
    }

    return next();
});

export default router;
```

**Routes in api:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('/unikit/check','AuthController@check');
});
```

**Controller method:**

```
public function check()
{
    try {
        JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response(['authenticated' => false]);
    }

    return response(['authenticated' => true]);
}
```

Also tried remove "unikit" dir and slash in routes but nothing happened.

Comment: You are making the ajax request to 'api/auth/check' but the route you show in the api is 'api/auth/unikit/check'.   Since you are getting a 405 error, api/auth/check must exist, perhaps as a 'get' method?

Answer (score 1):

After two hours of thinking i found a solution. Prefix of api routes in Provider need be 
modified for subfolder. `Route::prefix('/subfolder/api')` and problem solved! Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your route is: **/unikit/check**

```
Route::post('/unikit/check','AuthController@check');
```

But you are posting to **/check**

```
axios.post('api/auth/check')
```

Change this ^^ to:

```
axios.post('api/auth/unikit/check')
```

Comment: You 100% sure you are posting to the right link with the right formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like route problem. Method can't obtain a route:

```
{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",…}
exception
:
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
file
:
"C:\xampp\htdocs\unikit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php"
line
:
255
message
:
""
trace
:
[,…]
```

Routes list:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI            | Name | Action                                    | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | api/auth/check |      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@check | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | {vue?}         | home | Closure                                   | web        |
+--------+----------+----------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```